# How can I associate NSG's and Subnets being created by loops in Terraform?

Tags: loops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file, terraform0.12+

Here is the code I am using to create subnets and nsgs I want to associate the NSG and subnet in the same script but I am unable to understand how can I get subnet IDs and NSG IDs which are being produced here and use them in the association resource. Thanks in advance for the help !

**First part of code** this is being used to create n no of Subnets and NSGs depends upon the parameter

```
provider "azurerm" {

  version = "2.0.0"
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "new-rg" {
  name     = var.rg_name
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "new-vnet" {
  name                = var.vnet_name
  address_space       = ["${var.vnet_address_space}"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.new-rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.new-rg.name


}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "test" {
  count                = "${length(var.subnet_prefix)}"
  name                 = "${element(var.subnet_subnetname, count.index)}"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.new-rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.new-vnet.name
  address_prefix       = "${element(var.subnet_prefix, count.index)}"

}


resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "new-nsg" {

    count        =  "${length(var.subnet_prefix)}"
  name                = "${element(var.subnet_subnetname, count.index)}-nsg"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.new-rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.new-rg.name
}
```

Below is the resource where i have to pass the parameters to create the association for the above subnets and nsgs being created.

**Second Part of code** Need to make the below code usable for above solution for n no of associations.

```
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "example" {

  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.example.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.example.id
}
```

How can associate the n number of subnets and nsgs being created by using 2nd part of code, I cant find my way to that

Comment: how do you add nsg securiity rules inside "azurerm_network_security_group" "new-nsg" using loop like security_rule { } if we have more than one rules per subnets ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was able to solve the issue mentioned by me above the following code contains the solution for the mentioned scenario for the problem.

```
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "snet-nsg-association" {

count = length(var.subnet_subnetname)
subnet_id                 = element(azurerm_subnet.multi-snet.*.id, count.index)
network_security_group_id = element(azurerm_network_security_group.new-nsg.*.id, count.index)

}
```

Comment: This has a bug. This gets destroyed on next `terraform apply`
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3077

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good case for for_each. Here is some code I'm using for AWS (the same logic applies as far as I can tell)-

(var.nr_azs is just an int, formatlist is used because for_each only likes strings)

```
locals {
  az_set = toset(formatlist("%s", range(var.nr_azs))) # create a list of numbers and convert them to strings)
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  for_each                = local.az_set
  availability_zone       = random_shuffle.az.result[each.key]
  cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.main.cidr_block, 8, each.key)
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
}

resource "aws_eip" "nat_gw" {
  vpc = true
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "gw" {
  for_each      = aws_subnet.private
  allocation_id = aws_eip.nat_gw.id
  subnet_id     = each.value.id
}

resource "aws_route_table" "private_egress" {
  for_each = aws_nat_gateway.gw
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.main.id

  route {
    cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = each.value.id
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "private" {
  for_each       = local.az_set
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.private[each.key].id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.private_egress[each.key].id
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kyle for the response, I agree with your solution but in my case i am using Count loop and wanted to have a solution for doing it with count loop, Since i have specific approach for what I am doing ! I really appreciate your answer and it gave me a new approach as well thanks.

Comment: @Sarmad , how do you add nsg securiity rules inside "azurerm_network_security_group" "new-nsg" using loop like security_rule { } if we have more than one rules per subnets ?

Comment: @s_k_t I am not sure what you mean, if you can clarify more.